# Segmentation Fault error on Apache Httpd

Tags: apache, https, arm

While trying to configure an `SSL` enabled `Apache HTTPD Server` in `ARM Linux`, (Kernel `3.2.0`) I am getting the below error. The same build is working fine in a `Kernel 3.2.5+`. How do I sort this out? Do I have to go for `Kernel 3.2.5+`?

```
[mpm_event:notice] [pid 1465:tid 1074360320] AH00489: Apache/2.4.3 (Unix) OpenSSL/1.0.0g configured -- resuming normal operations

[core:notice] [pid 1465:tid 1074360320] AH00094: Command line: '/usr/local/apache2/bin/httpd'

[core:notice] [pid 1465:tid 1074360320] AH00052: child pid 4093 exit signal Segmentation fault (11)

[core:notice] [pid 1465:tid 1074360320] AH00052: child pid 4094 exit signal Segmentation fault (11)

[core:notice] [pid 1465:tid 1074360320] AH00052: child pid 4095 exit signal Segmentation fault (11)

[core:notice] [pid 1465:tid 1074360320] AH00052: child pid 4178 exit signal Segmentation fault (11)

[mpm_event:notice] [pid 1465:tid 1074360320] AH00494: SIGHUP received.  Attempting to restart

AH00557: httpd: apr_sockaddr_info_get() failed for beaglebone

AH00558: httpd: Could not reliably determine the server's fully qualified domain name, using 127.0.0.1. Set the 'ServerName' directive globally to suppress this message

[mpm_event:notice] [pid 1465:tid 1074360320] AH00489: Apache/2.4.3 (Unix) OpenSSL/1.0.0g configured -- resuming normal operations

[core:notice] [pid 1465:tid 1074360320] AH00094: Command line: '/usr/local/apache2/bin/httpd'

[core:notice] [pid 1465:tid 1074360320] AH00052: child pid 4390 exit signal Segmentation fault (11)
```

**EDIT 1**

Tried creating core dump directory for the dump in `httpd.conf` for the `SEGFAULT` debugging. But there are no directories created also.

Comment: do you have `opcache` or `php-APC` running ?

Comment: @FranciscoCorralesMorales No, the core dump is also not getting created.